# Invalid use of incomplete type with templates and decltype

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, decltype

I need to make the following work.

This is a reduced version of my actual code, but basically the difficulty is the same, i.e., to deduce the return type of a factory method.

Specifically, I need either the second or third variant of `DeduceObjectT` (both commented), instead of the first, which requires the `FactoryT::ObjectT` typedef.

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

template<class FactoryT>
using DeduceObjectT = typename FactoryT::ObjectT;
//template<class FactoryT>
//using DeduceObjectT = typename decltype(std::declval<FactoryT>().create())::element_type;
//template<class FactoryT>
//using DeduceObjectT = typename std::result_of<decltype(&FactoryT::create)(FactoryT)>::type::element_type;

template<class FactoryT>
struct FactoryUser
{
    typedef DeduceObjectT<FactoryT> ObjectT;
};

template<class FactoryUserT>
struct Foo
{
    typedef typename FactoryUserT::ObjectT ObjectT;
};

struct StringFactory
{
    typedef std::string ObjectT; // want to omit this

    std::unique_ptr<std::string> create()
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    Foo<FactoryUser<StringFactory>> t;
};

int main()
{
    StringFactory f;
    return 0;
}
```

After numerous tries I still get 'error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct StringFactory’'.

I also tried deducing the type by means of a default template argument of `FactoryUser`.

I really don't understand, why am I getting the error considering that the point that triggers instantiation of all templates is at the end -- the line that declares the data member `t`.

Compiler is gcc 4.7.3. with -std=c++0x -O0

Comment: Note that I was able to compile the 3rd variant using Visual Studio 2013. A friend was able to compile the 3rd variant using clang 3.4.1 and gcc 4.9 as well.

Comment: Deleted my answer as you were correct that it was an approximation at best. Also, note that to test the 3rd variation we used [this online compiler](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) if you want to see it working there. Using g++4.7 does yield a compiler error for the 3rd variation as you described.

Comment: @PeterClark I see the third variant (with result_of) compiles also with gcc 4.8.1

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this instead:

```
template <typename Factory>
struct ProductTypedef
{
  typedef typename decltype(std::declval<Factory>().create())::element_type ObjectT;
};

struct StringFactory : public ProductTypedef<StringFactory> // CRTP
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> create()
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

Comment: This has no chance of compiling, you moved the "usage" of the StringFactory class higher in the program - on the line with `public ProductTypedef<StringFactory>` - which is before the definition of `create()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter `Foo` a little bit for your code to work:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

template<class FactoryT>
using DeduceObjectT = typename FactoryT::ObjectT;

template<class FactoryT>
struct FactoryUser
{
    typedef DeduceObjectT<FactoryT> ObjectT;
};

// Provide a way for ObjectType to be specified at the time 
// the template is instantiated.
template<class FactoryUserT, typename ObjectType = typename FactoryUserT::ObjectT>
struct Foo
{
    typedef ObjectType ObjectT;
};

struct StringFactory
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> create()
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    Foo<FactoryUser<StringFactory>, std::string> t;
};

int main()
{
   StringFactory f;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes but the whole idea was to deduce std::string in the line where you declare data member `t`.

Comment: @haelix, what do you wish to gain by that? You have to specify `std::string` somewhere. Why not specify it in declaring `t`?

Comment: It would be nice to automatically deduce the return type of the factory method, without specifying that type anywhere else